# recommendation for a package and bibliography style

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

I appreciate it if you let me know which package and bibliography style should be used to have the bibliography with the following properties:

1- citation in the text should be like this: (Doe et al., 2000)

2- alphabetical sort of the references based on the last name of the first author

3- having this pattern for references with more than one author without abbreviating the first names:

LastName_1, FirstName_1, FirstName_2 LastName_2, and FirstName_3 LastName_3

such as:

Doe, John, David Dane, and Marry Dewy (2000). "This and that". In: Journal of Deep Understanding of Things.

Comment: `biblatex`'s `authoryear` style might also be of interest to you (see [this example document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/50-style-authoryear.pdf); also have a look at the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)). `biblatex` is very versatile and easy-to-costomise, but also slightly hard to get one's head round at first. See also [`biblatex` for idiots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864) and [What to do to switch to `biblatex`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864).

Comment: It seems to me the `authoryear` style does quite exactly what you want save for the full list of names in the bibliography which can be achieved by `maxbibnames=999`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the **authordate1** style would suit your needs best. Also, make sure to use \usepackage{natbib} as this allows for (Author et al., 2000) type of citations in the text.

By the way, I find the following website very useful when looking for a bibliography style myself http://nodonn.tipido.net/bibstyle.php It lets you filter and find the bibliography styles depending on your needs.

Comment: I tried authordate1. The problem with it is that an ampersand is used in stead of "and". Moreover, the format of the names for the second and third authors are like this: LastName, FirstName

Any other recommendation?

Comment: You're right, sorry. It seems that you will have to generate your style yourself, as none comes to mind which would suit all your requirements exactly. However, you can use the following **Bst generator** to build one if needed [http://www.podoblaz.net/cml/?id=39](http://www.podoblaz.net/cml/?id=39). I hope this helps as a first step and someone else will know more than me :)